# Inline-flex not working in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBjZGx

In firefox:[image]

Then in Chrome: [image]

I don't know what's causing this. I tried removing the vertical title but the empty space is still there.

Here is the code:

```css
section{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
a{
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: calc(2 * 1cm);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: .2rem solid #282323;
  border-right: .2rem solid #282323;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: currentcolor;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: center none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow .5s,transform 1s;
}
a:first-child{
  background: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
a:last-child{
  background: orange;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a>
    <p>
      
    </p>
    
    <h3 class="flex">
      <div>
        T
      </div>
      <div>
        i
      </div>
      <div>
        t
      </div>
      <div>
        t
      </div>
      <div>
        l
      </div>
      <div>
        e
      </div>
    </h3>
  </a><a>
    <p>
      don't click!
      link link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbb
      link link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbb
    </p>
  </a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `vertical-align: top;` to your anchor tag. It seems like you have to explicitly set this value in chrome

Snippet below

```css
section {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

a {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: calc(2 * 1cm);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: .2rem solid #282323;
  border-right: .2rem solid #282323;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: currentcolor;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: center none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow .5s, transform 1s;
  vertical-align: top;
}

a:first-child {
  background: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

a:last-child {
  background: orange;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
section{
  font-size:0
}
section * {
  font-size:initial
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a>
    <p>

    </p>

    <h3 class="flex">
      <div>
        T
      </div>
      <div>
        i
      </div>
      <div>
        t
      </div>
      <div>
        t
      </div>
      <div>
        l
      </div>
      <div>
        e
      </div>
    </h3>
  </a>
  <a>
    <p>
      don't click! link link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink
      link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbb link link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link
      link link your asss to the bbbbblink link link link link your asss to the bbbbb
    </p>
  </a>
</section>
```